# JPA: query matching many-to-may properties of unrelated entities

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee

I've got the following three entities:

```
@Entity
public class Item {
    [...]
    @ManyToOne(optional = false) 
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private ItemDescriptor asset;
    [...]
}

@Entity
public class ItemDescriptor {
    [...]
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<ContentPlan> contentPlans;
    [...]
}

@Entity
public class Tenant {
    [...]
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<ContentPlan> contentPlans;
    [...]
}
```

Now, I'm looking for a JPA query to give me:

**For given Tenant t, get all Items i where i.asset.contentPlans is in
t.contentPlans**

I've found several realted soultions, but none of them really solved the problem with this setting. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
SELECT i FROM Item i, Tenant t WHERE i.asset.contentPlans IN (t.contentPlans) AND t = :tenant
```

I guess this should to the job..?